# How to read a binary file in chunks?

Tags: python, performance

I have a binary file for images and their names that's fairly large and I need to splice it every `n*m` and every `n*m+x` (consistent offset for filename). Knowing the byte offset (`n*m+x`) how can I process these images faster?

Order doesn't matter and probably done asynchronously.

Comment: You can specify the chunk sizes when you call `file.read()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and how to provide a [mre]. Please note that your title must summarize your question; to that end, I edited your title but please make sure it still agrees with your original intent

Comment: It would also help people answer your question if you provided some more information, such as a [mre] of what you already have. I think it is unlikely that reading the file in chunks will speed up your processing, unless your file isn't large enough to read into memory all at once.

Comment: For the offsets, you might also need seek. see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects